# Updating data on mobile devices using App Engine (preferably avoiding "hot tablets")

Tags: google-app-engine, mobile, google-cloud-datastore

Some background information for context: I am building an app (iOS + android) with about six sorts of core objects (User, Kind, Event, Tag, Image and Trust). Users can create new users and then share this new user with other users (e.g. a parent can create a child, and invite another user to act on this child).

For every user, one can (given sufficient rights, represented by Trust objects) add new events containing zero or more tags, and zero or more images. Every event is also part of a "class" (it is of a certain "kind", represented by Kind objects).

Events have a timestamp (java.util.Date), so they can be displayed to the user in chronological order, and all objects contain a "modified" timestamp.

I use Java on app engine, but I believe this question to be of a general nature. Also, no objects are embedded in others, only keys (i.e. an Event object has a list of Image keys, not Image objects).

Now, the challenge is this: How can I in an efficient manner check the datastore for updates on all these types? My naïve prototype implementation does this: On the mobile device I currently poll the server every so often (currently every five minutes or whenever the user sends an update to the server), check a list of trusts to find the users the poller can see, and for each type (User, Kind, Event, Tag, Image, Trust) ask the datastore for objects related to this user that have a modified date more recent than the last time it polled. This is clearly way too many calls to the datastore.

If the app engine datastore has the "hot tablets" problem (cf. http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/ ), how can I efficiently ask the server for updates since I last checked? Adding a timestamp causes a bottleneck, apparently. Yet I want to update the mobile client with changes done since it last asked. (I know this bottleneck is unlikely to affect me on this project, but I have another project in March where this might become a real issue.)

To summarize, the question is: What are best practices for updating mobile clients with new/modifed data using app engine?

Thank you for reading my wall of text, I hope I have managed to convey the question and its context in a somewhat comprehensible manner.

Ex animo,
 - Alexander.

Comment: You really don't have to worry about hot tablets here. For the tablets containing the index rows with the timestamps to be 'hot', you would have to be writing thousands - possibly tens of thousands - of rows per second for a sustained period.

Answer (score 0):

(This was originally part of the question, but I edited it out as it is really an attempt to answer part of it.)

I believe I can use Query Cursors (cf. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html ) to make things slightly more efficient. It should keep a reference to the location in the index that has already been reached (the index being sorted on the modified timestamp), so it can start the search at that point. The cost is to store and transmit this cursor per device. Comments on this is also welcome (it is related to the main question of how to efficiently update clients).